# Gitlab multi project CI

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab

I have a complex LaTeX set of projects composed of the following directories.

```
PACKAGE/
SCRIPTS/
AUX/
PROJ1/
PROJ2/
...
```

Each PROJ1, PROJ2, ... is a book. To build PROJ1/, for example, I have a set of scripts in the SCRIPT folder. These scripts copy some files in the AUX/ folder to each PROJ1/ folder. The PACKAGE/ folder should be present to compile the book.
Therefore, for the files in PACAKGE/, SCRIPTS/ and AUX/ are common to each book (PROJ1, PROJ2, ...) but independent of them. Therefore I think I have to keep each folder in a separate git repository.

Now, I would like to use the **gitlab-ci** facility to build each PROJ*/. I know that I have to setup a docker runner, but my problem is how to do in a way that I do it using multiple repositories. I would like to build the books, not only when I commit to PORJ*, but also when I commit to AUX or PACKAGE. **How should I setup multi-project CI?**

NOTE: When I am coding a certain PROJ/ I made changes to PACKAGE and AUX that may break other books. I thought that I may relate each PROJ1, PROJ2, to PACKAGES and AUX, configuring PACKAGE and AUX as submodules of PROJ (It is my understanding that in this way I link each book to a specific version of AUX and PACKAGE). Will using submodules make easier to setup multi-project Ci? Is it a good idea to use the submodules this way? (I am aware that with submodules it is easy to make mistakes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your question is actually two parts. First how to create multiple git repositories and use one (the shared code) in others (the books). Second how to use gitlab CI to trigger build in case of change to any of the repos.

First part is easy, you need one repository that contains shared code (SCRIPTS, AUX, ...) and for each book a repo that contains book data AND shared repo as a submodule. See [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) if you dont know what they are.

This far you have solved half of the problem. On Gitlab, CI needs specific setup when using git submodules, [see here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/git_submodules.html) for the setup instructions. This way each book repo can be built. Last step is to setup the shared repo to trigger the build on all book repos. This can be done using trigger URLs as [described here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/triggers/).